# Setting parent attribute value from child window using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a complex requirement and unable to resolve it.

I have a parent window, that has the functionality to added a student name. Number of students that can be added is dynamic, that means there could be 1 or more input fields, so the input field names go like [0].name, [1].name, [2].name etc. For every field when the user enters 3 characters a child window pops up with a list of names and a radio button to select the name.

In the child window, when the user selects a radio button and submits/saves, I want to populate the parent window with the name selected in the child window and close the child window.

The tricky part is how to identify the parent input variable that called the child window.

Below code works since I hard-coded the input field name:

```
function confirm() {
    window.opener.document.getElementById("[0].name").value = mySelection;;
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? some code would be nice

Comment: `window.parent` identifies the parent window.

Comment: Do you mean the parent is `window.open`-ing child windows, or what?

Comment: Why are you doing this with new windows rather than a dialog in the current window?

Comment: All depends on how you code the dialogs.

Comment: How is that an `id`?

Comment: This is the only way I know not sure about how to implement a dialog option.

Comment: Child, as in `<iframe>` or child as in a window opened via url or `window.open()`? If you're the one doing the coding on both pages and they are in the same domain I would do like `var opes = open(/* params here*/)`. Then you just work off `opes`. Yeah, you can leave off the `window.` as it is implicit.

Comment: hi, I am using window.open(). I did not quite follow your response, can you please elaborate.